# Size of black bars in video?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I am developing a WPF C# video player with the MediaElement.
Some videos contain black bars at the top and bottom. I want to resize the picture i.e. to 120% so that no black bars are shown when I play these videos.
Now the question is how I can measure the size of the black bars. If i.e. a video has a height of 800 pixels I want to measure the height of the black bars. If there are 50 pixels black at the top and 50 pixels on the bottom then I will calculate that I have to resize the picture i.e. to 112%.
I guess I could make a screenshot of the video and then analyze that picture to find out how many black pixels are at the top and bottom (I have no idea how complicated that would be). But I guess and hope there is an easier way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure these black bars are the video content? It seems to me that it's about aspect ratio and automatic video content fitting in the `MediaElement` container. Have you tried to play those videos with "standard" media players, e. g. Windows Media, VLC or MPC?

Comment: @dymanoid: I am sure it’s the video.   
I understand your comment and in some cases there is obviously some part of the screen not filled by the video because of the aspect ratio. But there are some videos which include the black bars.

Comment: Well, it will be a tough job. First of all, you have to find a non-black frame in the video, and it could be the 1st or the 100th frame. That's not easy using just WPF's `MediaElement`. You could grab the frames one-by-one using e.g. `RenderTargetBitmap`, but that will take a lot of time, I suppose. And the user will first see the unscaled video while you're searching. Perhaps you should consider DirectShow or Media Foundation for this task.

Answer (score 0):

This is the beginning of my answer: I just wrote a quick and dirty solution with the screenshot.
I used RenderTargetBitmap to create a screenshot with the height of the video but just 1 pixel wide. Then I used the BitmapSource.CopyPixels Method to extract the single pixels and then I looped through the pixels from top to bottom. It works, and it work fast enough for me (<30ms for the whole procedure).
I will publish the complete code when it’s done.
I am still interested if there is an easier way to do this. My own answer is just one answer but I am happy to accept something better as “the answer”.